# Вывод онлайн данных из django, из БД на html страницу без обновления

Tags: html, django

хочу выводить онлайн данные из БД раз в секунду не обновляя страницу.
вот файл HTML:

```
<div class="value_style"  id="content">  ₽ </div>

<script>
function show()
     {
         $.ajax({
             url:  '{% url 'get_response' %}',
             data: {
            'inputValue': 0
            },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(html){
                 $("#content").html(html);
             }
         });
     }

     $(document).ready(function(){
         show();
         setInterval('show()',1000);
     });
 </script>
```

вот код views.py:

```
def answer_me(request):
    z = 0
    data = Emit.objects.all()
    for x in data:
        if x.price != None:
            z = json.dumps(x.price)
    return JsonResponse(z)
```

вот urls:

```
 path('get_response', views.answer_me, name='get_response'),
```

выдает ошибку:
 'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.

понимаю что накосячил с форматом, но как правильно сделать не пойму....

Comment: Попробуйте `return JsonResponse(z, save=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Тебе не нужно делать json.dumps .

json.dumps уже встроен в JsonResponse

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects